# IdentityServer4 how to create identity token?

Tags: c#, jwt, token, identityserver4, c#-2.0

I follow several tutorials and the IdentityServer4 documentation and its terminology : [Terminology](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/intro/terminology.html)
But I do not understand which endpoint to get a id token for a user.
I thought I can change the existing way to have access token to get the id token, but none of method give a result :

```
        var disco = new DiscoveryClient("http://localhost:55678");
        var discoResponse = disco.GetAsync().Result;
        if (discoResponse.IsError)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(discoResponse.TokenEndpoint, "mvc", "secret");
        var tokenResponse = tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(context.EmailAddress, context.Password, "email");
        var token = tokenResponse.Result;
```

I understand that resourceownerpassword way is only for access to a resource using the password, not for identify the user.

When i tried to configure my jwtendpoint, i thought i can ask a id token but no result :

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(opts =>
            {
                opts.Authority = "http://localhost:55678/";
                opts.Audience = "api1";
                opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                opts.SaveToken = true;
            });
```

I don't know which endpoint user to get the jwt id token.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You return null if `discoResponse.IsError` but don't output any information. Is that where the code is breaking? You should be checking  `discoResponse.Error` and `tokenResponse.Error` - that may give some insight into what is going wrong.

Comment: No error, i debug and the discover point is ok, but my real problem is that i get access_token not the id_token which is empty.

Comment: Just from curiosity - why resource owner password grant?

Comment: Because i want to give access for a user using his password....

Comment: Username/password is also available with other flows: "... the general recommendation is to use an interactive flow like implicit or hybrid for user authentication instead." from http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html#resource-owner-password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get **identity tokens** with **password grant**.

The endpoint to use to get an **identity token** is the [**Authorize EndPoint**](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html) but you can't use **password grant** with this endpoint.

You can access user information (claims) from the [UserInfo Endpoint](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/userinfo.html) using the **access token**